# How to make textField in TableViewCell editable when edit button of NavigationBar is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Developing an iOS application with Xcode ver 9.2, Swift.

When the edit button on the top right of the NavigationBar is pressed, how to change the textField in the TableViewCell to make it editable?
To prevent the TextField from being edited in the initial display, I set textField.isEnabled = false with awakeFromNib() in the TableViewCell.swift.
When the edit button is pressed, I want to set it to true so that I can edit the TextField.
Could you tell me how?

Relationship between object placement and code (in parentheses) is below.

NavigationController - TableViewController (TableViewController.swift) - TableViewCell (TableViewCell.swift) - TextField

Here is the code.

TableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, TableViewCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var ttableView: UITableView!

    var array:[String] = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inputCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.textField.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: TableViewCell, value: String) -> () {
        let path = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: cell.convert(cell.bounds.origin, to: tableView))
        array[(path?.row)!] = value
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
            array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: sourceIndexPath) as! TableViewCell
        let moveData = cell.textField.text
        array.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        array.insert(moveData!, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

}
```

TableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: TableViewCell, value: String) -> ()
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate! = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.returnKeyType = .done

        // To prevent the TextField from being edited in the initial display 
        textField.isEnabled = false
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.delegate.textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: self, value: textField.text!)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

I added the following from the first time question and answers.

[Editing screen shot: after edit button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Suxeh.png)

If there are many elements of the array, the cells will be outside the screen, but I want to make all textField editable as well.

```
var array:[String] = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm", "nnn", "ooo", "ppp", "qqq", "rrr", "sss", "ttt"]
```

[Editing screen shot for many elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNYfg.png)

**Finally resolved code**

TableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, TableViewCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var ttableView: UITableView!

//    var array:[String] = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"]

    var array:[String] = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm", "nnn", "ooo", "ppp", "qqq", "rrr", "sss", "ttt"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(rightBarButtonItemTapped))
    }

    // handle tap by button...
    @objc func rightBarButtonItemTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        ttableView.setEditing(!ttableView.isEditing, animated: true)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = ttableView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.style = ttableView.isEditing ? .done : .plain
        ttableView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
            guard let cell = cell as? TableViewCell else { return }
            cell.textField.isEnabled = ttableView.isEditing
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inputCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.textField.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.textField.isEnabled = tableView.isEditing
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: TableViewCell, value: String) -> () {
        let path = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: cell.convert(cell.bounds.origin, to: tableView))
        array[(path?.row)!] = value
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
            array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        if tableView.isEditing {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
        } else {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: sourceIndexPath) as! TableViewCell
        let moveData = cell.textField.text
        array.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        array.insert(moveData!, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

}
```

TableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: TableViewCell, value: String) -> ()
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate! = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.returnKeyType = .done
        //textField.isEnabled = false
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.delegate.textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: self, value: textField.text!)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: If you know's the indexPath.Using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you can get Cell and it's sub everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should handle navigation button tap, find cell(s) with `textField` and then set `textField.isEnabled = true`.

You can do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // in your code `self.editButtonItem` is the `UIBarButtonItem`, so make sure that it configured properly
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit, target: self, action: #selector(rightBarButtonItemTapped))
}

// handle tap by button...
@objc func rightBarButtonItemTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // and set `textField.isEnabled` to all `visibleCells`
    ttableView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
        guard let cell = cell as? TableViewCell { else return }
        cell.textField.isEnabled = true
    }

    // or set `isEnabled` to specific `textField` at index 0

    if let cell = ttableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) {
        cell.textField.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

**UPD.**

Base on your screenshot you:

1. doesn't need to set `textField.isEnabled = false`
2. you just need `setEditing` for tableView and show appropriate title for button in navigation bar.

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(rightBarButtonItemTapped))
}

@objc func rightBarButtonItemTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    ttableView.setEditing(!ttableView.isEditing, animated: true)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = ttableView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.style = ttableView.isEditing ? .done : .plain
}
```

**LAST UPD**

Ok, now only steps you should do:

1. remove from `awakeFromNib` code that disable `textField`
2. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in your viewController write `cell.textField.isEnabled = tableView.isEditing`
3. to set tableView in editing mode use my `UPD` code
4. to enable all `textField`s in cells you should use approach from original answer with `visibleCells` (i updated this part, now you shouldn't have any error). note, that this code apply only for currently visible cells. for others it also works, but `set textField enabled` part goes in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method because these cells will appear on the screen.

Comment: I added the screen shot and comment to my question.

Comment: (1)navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem( ... => delete and move cell does not work. (2) ttableView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in ... => Error occured. Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'textField'

Comment: I want to make it impossible to edit textField before edit mode(before Edit button is pressed). And after Edit button is pressed, I want to change textField is editable.

Comment: @TakeYourMark, make final updates to my answer. check this out.

Comment: I implemented 1 to 3 but failed with 4. 2 error and 1 warning messages occurred in "guard let cell = cell as? TableViewCell { else return }". Error messages are "Expected expression", "Expected 'else' after 'guard' condition". Warning message is "Value 'cell' was defined but never used; consider replacing with boolean test".

Comment: When I changed the code to "guard let cell = cell as? TableViewCell else { return }", it works fine! The problem was solved and I could what I wanted to do. I will post the final code in the question column. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can do so by creating an action of your navigation barbutton item , and in that action you can simply do the textField enabled, as shown below:

```
 @IBAction func editTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        print("editTapped")
        for i in 0..< ttableView.visibleCells.count{
       let cell = ttableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as! TableViewCell
            cell.textField.isEnabled = true

        }
    }
```

Comment: I added the screen shot and comment to my question.

Comment: Visible textField in the screen can now be editable. If there are many elements of the array, the cells will be outside the screen, but I want to make all textField editable as well.

Comment: Editing of any cell is possible only when it is visible, so the code will work fine , if there are 'n' number of cells.

Comment: The problem was solved and I could what I wanted to do. I will post the final code in the question column. Thank you for your answer!